# $wpdb->update prefixes database name to table when executing query

Tags: multisite, database

I run into a problem I can't seem to fix. I went back and forth and even used `$wpdb->prepare()` and `$wpdb->query()` functions, nothing helps.

`$table_prefix."users"` returns `wp_2qttgdv7ac_2_users` (slightly changed in post for security purposes). Yes, I've tried `$wpdb->prefix` as well. Same result.

```
$wpdb->update($table_prefix."users", array('user_email' => $fetch_data['new_email']), array('user_login' => $fetch_data['username']))
```

This was not working, but on running...

```
var_dump( $wpdb->last_error)
```

I get the error:

> string(59) "Table 'A41K421094D3615.wp_2qttgdv7ac_2_users' doesn't exist"

Here *A41K421094D3615* is the database name. I am running in a multi-site environment. However, accessing custom tables does not add database name in front of the table. How can I get it to stop adding it? Or at least make it honor the table. Usually database_name.table_name should work, right? However, it's returning that it does not exist. Any suggestions?

Comment: WordPress isn't adding the table name to the SQL: MySQL is including it for context when it's generating the error. Try `use A41K421094D3615; select * from wp_2qttgdv7ac_2_users;` in MySQL and you'll get the same error even though the database name wasn't in the SELECT. Does that table actually exist?

Comment: You are right wp_2qttgdv7ac_2_users doesn't exist when I confirmed with PhpMyAdmin. Users for multisite is saved on the same table wp_2qttgdv7ac_users as other sites on a multisite network. Using $wpdb->prefix and $table_prefix provides "wp_2qttgdv7ac_2_" - using $wpdb->base_prefix solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use $wpdb->base_prefix for 'users' table.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks